# How to arrange the word of a given string in ascending oredr in php?

Tags: php

I want to get a proper solution for my coding.

**Step 1**. I first break it into array

**Step 2**. then split each explode value

**Step 3**. then sort it by a for loop

```
<?php 
$st ="It is a test";
$exp = explode(' ',strtolower($st));
print_r($exp);
$c =0;
$p =0;
for($i=0;$i<count($exp);$i++){
  $t = str_split($exp[$i]);
  $ch = $t[0];
   if($c==0){

       $arr[$p]=$exp[$i];      
       $temp = $ch;    
   }else{
       if(ord($ch)<ord($temp)){
          $tp = $arr[$p-1];
          $arr[$p-1] = $exp[$i];
          $arr[$p] = $tp;        
       }else{
          $arr[$p] = $exp[$i];
       }
} 
 $temp = $ch;  
 $p++;
 $c++; 
}
print_r($arr);
?>
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Post your expected output

Comment: in alphabetical order?

Comment: yes in alphabetical oreder......

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you want, but I think this is what you want.

```
<?php 
$st ="It is a test";
$exp = explode(' ',strtolower($st));
sort($exp);

for($x = 0; $x <count($exp); $x++) {
     echo $exp[$x];
     echo "<br>";
}
?>
```

Comment: I want the answer without using sort function

Comment: @ArunimaDas What about usort? Have a look on this: http://www.the-art-of-web.com/php/sortarray/

Comment: I want to sort the string using own technique not using any sort function that defined in php

Comment: @ArunimaDas Then take a look at this:-
https://dissectionbydavid.wordpress.com/2010/09/27/sorting-arrays-in-php-without-using-sort-ksort-array_multisort-etc/

Comment: using recursive function

Comment: @ArunimaDas You can try that, if need help you can always post here again. I'm sure developers are glad to help :)